# bundle install fails too many open files. How can I get it working again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I'm running 4.2.6, on ruby 2.1.8p440 on MacOS 10.12 Sierra, Bundler version 1.12.0.rc

I get this when I try to 'bundle install'

```
jay-gischers-macbook-pro-110:ilarp gischer$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/Retrying fetcher due
to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not reach host index.rubygems.org.     
Check your network connection and try again.
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Errno::EMFILE Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - 
/Users/gischer/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.80.9e8aca59a0c3a407fba89eb64623162d/info/selenium-webdriver

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Errno::EMFILE Too many open files @ rb_sysopen -
/Users/gischer/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.80.9e8aca59a0c3a407fba89eb64623162d/info/sqlite3/Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:74:in `request_issue_report_for': cannot load such file -- bundler/env (LoadError)
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:40:in `log_error'
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /Users/gischer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I have seen this before and increased my limit with, for instance, ulimit -n 8196

This has worked in the past, it is not working now:

```
jay-gischers-macbook-pro-110:ilarp gischer$ sudo ulimit -n 8196
Password:
jay-gischers-macbook-pro-110:ilarp gischer$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4):Bundler::HTTPError Could not reach host index.rubygems.org. Check your network connection and try again.
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Errno::EMFILE Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - /Users/gischer/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.80.9e8aca59a0c3a407fba89eb64623162d/info/rspec-rails
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Errno::EMFILE Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - /Users/gischer/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.80.9e8aca59a0c3a407fba89eb64623162d/info/sprockets
```

Rebooting my system hasn't helped.  Closing down all my applications except for Terminal hasn't helped either. I ran a virus scan, too, using ClamXav, but it didn't find anything.  Very little has changed about my rails server, which wasn't running when I tried to run this in any case.  I found a vague suggestion from a few months ago Suggestions?  Workarounds?

Comment: More info:  This seems related to the contents of my Gemfile.  A fresh rails project will run bundle install just fine.

Comment: Ok, I just worked around the problem by changing source from "http://rubygems.org" to "https://rubygems.org"

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

to be

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

fixed the problem.  I'm not entirely sure why that is.  Maybe the real problem was access, and all those EMFILE messages were the result of some error cascade?